# Codefights ReverseParentheses Recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm stuck on a problem from Codefights Arcade question 13 in the intro. Below are the problem statement and my code so far. The outline of my thinking on how to solve the problem is to recursively work my way down/within the nested sequences and when I get to a single sequence (no nested sequences) reverse it, remove the parenthesis and return it. The base case for the recursion would be a string with no sequences that does not need to be reversed and would thus be returned up the call stack. I have two problems right now for sure, 1 of which is a big problem. I have an infinite recursion bug (bug 2 below). The reasons for the infinite recursion is that in the case of co(de(fight)s) it will recurse once adding a call to the stack with the shorter string (de(fight)s) dropping the "co" in the beginning, but then after that I get stuck in an infinite recursion of (de(fight)s) as the string. I am looking for some help in this problem. I would like to solve it via recursion, but am open to other ideas. In general, I find I still suck at recursion and am trying to improve in it.

**Problem Statement**

You have a string s that consists of English letters, punctuation marks, whitespace characters, and brackets. It is guaranteed that the parentheses in s form a regular bracket sequence.

Your task is to reverse the strings contained in each pair of matching parentheses, starting from the innermost pair. The results string should not contain any parentheses.

Example

For string s = "a(bc)de", the output should be
reverseParentheses(s) = "acbde".

Input/Output

[execution time limit] 0.5 seconds (cpp)

[input] string s

A string consisting of English letters, punctuation marks, whitespace characters and brackets. It is guaranteed that parentheses form a regular bracket sequence.

Constraints:
5 ≤ s.length ≤ 55.

Here are a few test cases that hit the major :

1. a(bc)de -> acbde
2. a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q -> apmnolkjihgfedcbq
3. co(de(fight)s) -> cosfighted
4. abc(cba)ab(bac)c -> abcabcabcabc

[output] string

**My Code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool hasSequence(string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == '(') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool hasSubSequence(string s) {
    int countOfLeftParen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == '(') {
            countOfLeftParen++;
        }
    }
    if (countOfLeftParen > 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

string removeParentheses(string s) {
    s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '('), s.end());
    s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ')'), s.end());
    return s;
}

string reverseSequence(string s) {
    string toReverse = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == '(') {
            while (s[i] != ')') {
                toReverse += s[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    //BUG1: bug here - this will reverse it, but it's not correct
    std::reverse(toReverse.begin(), toReverse.end());
    return toReverse;
}


std::string reverseParentheses(std::string s) {
    const char leftParen = '(';
    const char rightParen = ')';
    int leftParenCount = 0;
    int rightParenCount = 0;
    string needsReveresed;

    if (!(hasSequence(s))) {
        return s;
    }

    if (!(hasSubSequence(s))) {
        reverseSequence(s);
        return removeParentheses(s);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == leftParen) {
            leftParenCount++;
            while (rightParenCount < leftParenCount) {
                needsReveresed += s[i];
                i++;
                if (s[i] == rightParen) {
                    needsReveresed += s[i];
                    rightParenCount++;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    if (s[i] == leftParen) {
                        needsReveresed += s[i];
                        leftParenCount++;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            //BUG2: infinite recursion bug here. The string I pass down the recursion stack doesn't change
            s = reverseParentheses(needsReveresed);
        }
    }
    return s;
}


int main()
{
    string input = "co(de(fight)s)";
    string result = reverseParentheses(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's another way of looking at it: When you find an open, remove it, recurse in and pick up where you left off. When you find a close, remove it, reverse everything between start and the the close, and return the location of the next character to inspect. Probably solve in 15-20 lines of code. Might not be top speed, though.

Comment: Without recursion -- You can use a stack to solve this problem by using the right parenthesis as a trigger to reverse and "unwind" the stack of a built up stack of characters.  Similar to how infix to postfix exercises are solved.  This should also be a short solution, around 20 lines.

Comment: *I am looking for some help in this problem. I would like to solve it via recursion, but am open to other ideas.* -- Don't want to post solutions here, but my suggestion of using a stack is very simple, probably easier than trying to do recursion.  Wrote a solution within 5 or so minutes that passes all of your test data you are showing using `std::stack<std::string>`, and `std::reverse()` to reverse strings.  There is no need to remove parentheses, checking for subsequence, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReverseParentheses - Codefights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254365/reverseparentheses-codefights)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you asked if there were other ways to solve this problem other than recursion.  Here is a (proposed) solution using a `std::stack<std::string>`:

```
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q";
    std::stack<std::string> stringStack;
    stringStack.push({});  // make sure we have one item in the stack.
```

So basically, we start out with a stack of one item, the empty string.  Then we go through each character:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(')
            stringStack.push({});
```

The strategy with checking for the left parenthesis is to create a new substring.  The creation of the substring is done by pushing on a brand new empty string onto the stack.

If the current character isn't a left parenthesis, we check if it's the right parenthesis.  This is where some of the magic is done.

```
        else if (s[i] == ')')
        {
            // reverse the string at current stack top
            std::string topString = stringStack.top();
            std::reverse(topString.begin(), topString.end());

            // remove this string from the stack
            stringStack.pop();

            // append the string onto the current top of stack
            // or if stack is empty, make the reversed string the
            // top of stack.
            if (stringStack.empty())
                stringStack.push(topString);
            else
                stringStack.top() += topString;
        }
```

So what did we do here?  We detected that the right parenthesis means "end of substring".  So we reverse the sequence of characters that are currently at the top of the stack, save the reversed string to a temporary, and then pop the stack of these characters.  After that we append onto the new top of stack these reversed characters.

Since the top of the stack now contains a built up string from previous characters, this is our "string builder".  The top of stack will always contain the final string at the end of processing.

If it's neither a left or right parenthesis, we just simply concatenate onto the current top of stack the input character:

```
        else
            stringStack.top() += s[i];
    }
}
```

That's it.  There is no removal of parentheses, no checking if we're in a subsequence already, etc.

Here is a [live example](https://ideone.com/BucrYd).

Note that I didn't try this with other input except for the test cases you have shown.  If there is an edge case that isn't covered, the code above should be able to be easily corrected to cover the edge cases.

Comment: That's an excellent solution, and for context when I reworked it to extract the logic into a standalone function that accepts S as a parameter, it passed all the tests with no issues in edge cases. A part of me still would like to get the recursive solution to work because it was my original concept, but this is a better solution. Your answer is cleaner, less code, and easier to debug. Thanks for the thoughtful explanation and walkthrough of your code!

Answer (score 1):

```
string reverseParentheses(string s) {
    int open = 0;
    int startInd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++){
        if (s[i] == '('){
            if (open == 0){
                startInd = i+1;
            }
            open++;
        }
        if (open == 1 && s[i] == ')'){
            string start = s.substr(0, startInd-1);
            string parens = s.substr(startInd, i - startInd);
            string revParens;
            for (int k = parens.length(); k >= 0 ; k--){
                if (parens[k] == '('){
                    revParens+=')';
                }
                else if (parens[k] == ')'){
                    revParens+='(';
                }else{
                revParens+=parens[k];
                }
            }
            string end = s.substr(i+1, s.length());
            return reverseParentheses(start + revParens + end);
        }
        if (s[i] == ')'){
            open--;
        }
    }
    return s;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my stab at it using recursion and iterators.  I had to sleep on it first.

```
void reverseStartingAt(std::string& working, std::string::iterator& itParenStart)
{
    auto itParenEnd = std::next(itParenStart);
    while (itParenEnd != working.end())
    {
        if (*itParenEnd == ')')
        {
            std::reverse(itParenStart, itParenEnd);                         // reverses ["(CBA)") ==> "ABC()"
            working.erase(std::prev(itParenEnd), std::next(itParenEnd));    // erases "ABC"["()x") ==> "ABCx"
            itParenStart = itParenEnd;                                      // Advance the start iterator to where the closing parenthesis was
            std::advance(itParenStart, -2);                                 // ... and subtract 2 to compensate for the removed "()"
            return;
        }
        else if (*itParenEnd == '(')
        {
            reverseStartingAt(working, itParenEnd);
        }
        itParenEnd++;
    }
}


std::string reverseInParentheses(std::string inputString)
{
    std::string working(inputString);
    for (auto itParenStart = working.begin(); itParenStart != working.end(); ++itParenStart)
    {
        if (*itParenStart == '(')
            reverseStartingAt(working, itParenStart);
    }

    return working;
}
```