# Allocation size overflow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hey guys the problem is I am trying to solve a coding problem with JavaScript but I am running into an allocation size overflow.

The problem is You have a string s that consists of English letters, punctuation marks, whitespace characters, and brackets. It is guaranteed that the parentheses in s form a regular bracket sequence.

Your task is to reverse the strings contained in each pair of matching parentheses, starting from the innermost pair. The results string should not contain any parentheses.

Example

For string s = "a(bc)de", the output should be
reverseParentheses(s) = "acbde".

Input/Output

[execution time limit] 4 seconds (js)

[input] string s

A string consisting of English letters, punctuation marks, whitespace characters and brackets. It is guaranteed that parentheses form a regular bracket sequence.

Constraints:
   5 ≤ s.length ≤ 55.

[output] string

```
function reverseParentheses(s) {

if(!s.includes('(')) {
 console.log(s)
 return s;
}


//Find last index of opening parentheses instance
let lastOpenIndex = s.lastIndexOf('(');

//Find the first index of closing parentheses instance
let firstCloseIndex = s.indexOf(')');

//Find the number of characters between last open parentheses and    first closing parentheses
let space = firstCloseIndex - lastOpenIndex - 1;

//Reverse items in parentheses
let reversedString = s.slice(lastOpenIndex + 1,firstCloseIndex).split('').reverse().join('')


//Create new string with reversed word and dropped parantheses
const newString = s.substring(0,lastOpenIndex) + reversedString + s.substring(firstCloseIndex + 1,s.length)

return reverseParentheses(newString)   


}

reverseParentheses("abc(cba)ab(bac)c")
```

The expected result given the string in the function call should be "abcabcabcabc" but is instead giving memory size allocation error. Just a side not the code does work with smaller inputs.

Comment: Make the function print step by step what it’s doing and think about your algorithm. Is it a proper one? What happens when you take the last ( and first ) in your test case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReverseParentheses - Codefights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254365/reverseparentheses-codefights)

Comment: That particular question (along with many, many others) has already been answered,  See the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and minimal implementation, one function that's responsible for getting the sub string, another that's responsible for replacing one parentheses at a time, then of course, the recursive function I've just called `reverse`.

```js
// Get a sub string.
const sub = s => /\(([^()]*)\)/i.exec(s)[1];

// Process one block.
const block = s => s.replace(/\(([^()]*)\)/i, [...sub(s)].reverse().join(''));

// Reverse parentheses.
const reverse = s => s.includes('(') ? reverse(block(s)) : s;

// Demo.
const test = "abc(cba)ab(bac)c";
console.log(reverse(test));
console.log(reverse("hello ((world)) !"));
```